# sampling from sklearn Kernel Density estimation

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, kernel-density

I'm using the `sample()` method for a KernelDensity that is fitted to my data's percentage changes. Are the samples from the sample method in the same units as my input data? I ask because documentation says that for the `score_sample()` method it actually returns the log density and I just want to make sure the same doesn't happen with the sample method or if there's a need to adjust the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: yes, the sample is in the same unit as my input data. I checked carefully and with a cold head :)